# How to put the number of the formula to the right side?

Tags: equations

I am using `LaTeX` to create a formula, however, I have found that the placement of the number (in my case, (2)) of the formula is too close. I want to put the number at the right side.

[image]

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
{C_m = (D_m_1, D_m_2, ..., D_m_k__m}), (m \in (1, j))
\end{equation}
\end{document}

\end{document}
```

How should I change my code?

Comment: Please extend your sniplet to a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is. Here there is no document class or preamble. Additionally your image does not match the code provided.

Comment: The code shown can not possibly make the ouput shown, so impossible to say what to change.

Comment: You must get an error from `D_m_1`  After _any_ error don't even look at the ouput, TeX only recovers enough to syntax check the rest of the document, not to make sensible output.

Comment: Is "formel" a math term I'm not familiar with, or should this be "formula"?

Comment: Sorry for that, I just updated my code

Comment: @frabjous: It's the German term for formula, which I assume is what OP meant.

Comment: sorry, I confuse german with english, formel mean formula

Comment: You changed your code, but you still didn't post a complete [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that), and your code still has errors. Use `D_{m1}` if you want "m1" as a subscript to D, or `D_{m_{1}}` if 1 should be a subsubscript on m.

Comment: Thanks for adding the document class, etc., but the subscript errors are still there, and the placement of the braces is odd. When I fix those I do not get the result you show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when I run your code on my computer, I get several error messages, due to the double subscript" (eg D_m_2). Use D_{m_2}.
You write you equation {......(........} ......). First, the {....} is not necessary in this case, and the (...) should be open and closed within the {...}, Ex: {....(...)... .}

Are all the parentheses really necessary?

The code below worked for me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        C_m = (D_{m_1}, D_{m_2}, ..., D_{mk_m}), (m \in (1, j))
    \end{equation}
\end{document
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works!

Comment: That doesn't change the position of the number, it just moves the formula itself slightly to the left. The OP must have been using different settings or the result was a byproduct of the code errors, as they're not getting it all the way on the right to begin with, as one would with your code, with or without the `\quad`.

Comment: and `...` should be `\dots

Answer (score 4):

The reason why the number is close to the equation is that a `}` is missed in the input. The codes should be revised and improved in the following way.

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
C_m = (D_{m1}, D_{m2},\cdots, D_{mk_m}),
\end{equation}
where $m \in (1, j)$.
\end{document}
```

[image]